# Position matplotlib text top right

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a scatter plot. I want to place two lines of text: PP=0.87 and SC=0.76. Now whenever I'm entering some text in the code it is placed in the bottom left corner of the curve instead of the top right please tell me what I should do.

What I'm getting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2wH3.png

I'm expecting in two lines:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5d81.jpg

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [6,9,4,7,3]
y = [4,9,3,5,3]
plt.text(-0.5, -0.25, 'PP=0.87 \n SC=0.76')
plt.scatter(x, y, c = 'k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: the first two numbers are the `x` and `y` coordinates of where to put the text... tweak those? (and maybe remove the space after `\n`)

Comment: Thanks. Ya, I was making a mistake with the coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the plt.text() function is:

```
plt.text(x, y, s)
```

These coordinates refer to the plot coordinates. Your coordinates are negative and so you get text in the bottom left.

Try:

```
plt.text(11, 10, "string")
```

Answer (score 10):

`plt.text` uses data coordinates by default. You can use axis coordinates like this:

```
plt.text(0.5, 0.25, 'PP=0.87 \n SC=0.76', transform=plt.gca().transAxes)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Reproducible Example with Screenshot**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()  # overrides default matplotlib settings with seaborn's

# Data
x = [6,9,4,7,3]
y = [4,9,3,5,3]
```

### Text placement with

**a) data coordinates**

```
plt.text(9.92, 8.71, 'PP = 0.87 \nSC = 0.76', 
         fontsize=10, fontfamily='Georgia', color='k',
         ha='center', va='center');
```

**b) axis coordinates**

```
plt.text(1.01, 0.85, 'PP = 0.87 \nSC = 0.76', 
         fontsize=10, fontfamily='Georgia', color='k',
         ha='left', va='bottom',
         transform=plt.gca().transAxes);
```

`transform=plt.gca().transAxes`   ←  specifies that x,y coordinates are for axis

[image]

#### c) AnchorBox

```
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText

x = [6,9,4,7,3]
y = [4,9,3,5,3]
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
plt.scatter(x, y, c = 'k')
anchored_text = AnchoredText('PP = 0.87 \nSC = 0.76', 
                             frameon=False, borderpad=0, pad=0.1, 
                             loc=1, bbox_to_anchor=[1.19,1], 
                             bbox_transform=plt.gca().transAxes,
                             prop={'color':'k','fontsize':10,
                                   'fontfamily':'Georgia'})
ax.add_artist(anchored_text)
```